# generate signatures of *.cma archives and / or easier ways to link with OCaml archive files

Tags: ocaml

In the same vein of using:

```
ocamlc -i foo.ml
```

to generate the default signature for *foo.ml* is there a way to generate signatures from compiled files (*.cmo) or archives (*.cma)?

My use case is that I have an archive **abcd.cma** I want to link with, containing numerous modules (say, modules *a*, *b*, *c* and *d*) and I don't want to bother with the multiple *.mli and *.cmi my Makefile would need to handle to compile and link the user-side code (that uses the library). E.g. say I have file **uses_a.ml** that uses only the **a** module found in the **abcd.cma** archive. My understanding is that to link with the **abcd.cma** module I would have to go through the following motions:

```
ocamlc -i a.ml > a.mli
ocamlc -c a.mli
ocamlc -c uses_a.ml  
ocamlc abcd.cma uses_a.cmo
```

Which seems too convoluted or impossible if I don't have access to the sources or the signature. Given that I provide the entire archive to the compiler at the last command it is not clear to me why I have to go through the ritual of compiling (or generating - if I have access to the sources) the specific signature file for the module I am using. The last command could have been interpreted by the tool as an invitation to use the "default" signature of any module present in the archive that subsequent modules on the line use. BTW I don't want to use automatic Makefile generation tools at this point.

Comment: OCaml throws away type information after the compile, more or less.  That's why the `-i` flag works with source (.ml) but not with objects (.cmo).  IMHO, a type-safe interface is not just rigamarole.  For what it's worth.

Comment: There is no need to generate a.mli - where did you get this? By default the inferred signature will be used if no mli is provided for the source file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to compile a.ml and a.mli, there is no point having a library.

A library is normally composed of a `abcd.cma` file (or both `abcd.a` and `abcd.cmxa` in native code) and the set of interfaces (.cmi files) of the modules that are exported from the library. So, normally, in your case, the file `a.cmi` should be provided altogether with the library.

In such a case, you just need to do:

```
 ocamlc -I path/to/directory/containing_a.cmi -c uses_a.ml
 ocamlc -o program.opt abcd.cma uses_a.cmo
```